# Debug Boo in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, boo

I just recently played with Rhino DSL and created a simple DSL using Boo. When I debugged my first code I was quite suprised to find out, that while debugging I was actually stepping through the boo file as well. That is awesome!

This was with Visual Studio 2008 Pro.

Now I switched my code to VS 2010 Pro ... and no more debugging in my Boo file :( What do I need to make VS 2010 step through my Boo file just like VS 2008 did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it - when I edit the boo-file and it get's re-compile while debugging I can step through the boo file. This works in VS2010 just the same as in VS2008. Obviuously I always modified my boo-file in VS2008; if I don't change the boo-file I also can't step through the file in VS2008.